# Load weights to new model, how much have been correctly loaded?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, transfer-learning

I want to load the weights from model A to model B.
Model B last few layers are a bit different, thus the weights for those layers should not be loaded.
I'm using [load_weights](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#load_weights) with parameters such that layer that are different are skipped.

```
load_weights(    filepath, by_name=True, skip_mismatch=True)
```

Is there a way to know the portion of weights that have correctly been loaded ?
I just want to make sure than ~90% of the weights get correctly loaded.

Comment: What does it mean for a weight to be correctly loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.testing`to check the difference between the weights from both models. For example,

```
np.testing.assert_allclose(
    A_model.layers[0].bias.numpy(), B_model.layers[0].bias.numpy()
)
```

`np.testing.assert_allclose` can give `%` mismatched elements:

```
a = [1.0, 2, 3] 
b = np.array([1.0, 8, 9])
try:
    np.testing.assert_allclose(a, b)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

exception prints

```
Not equal to tolerance rtol=1e-07, atol=0
Mismatched elements: 2 / 3 (66.7%)
Max absolute difference: 6.
Max relative difference: 0.75
 x: array([1., 2., 3.])
 y: array([1., 8., 9.])
```